# ESP8266 wireless sensor network with Sming framework

Tags: wifi, esp8266, sming

I am attempting to create a wireless sensor network using ESP8266 devices and [the Sming framework](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming). Most of the code I have currently got comes from [the basic WiFi example](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/tree/develop/samples/Basic_WiFi). I have been able to establish connections between up to 3 devices and do not foresee any problems connecting more.

I would like to have a sink node to which all the other devices send their data. This sink node could either be one of the ESP8266 devices or for example my smartphone with a WiFi hotspot. Sending a message from one device to a sink node could take multiple hops.

My problem lies with how I am going to have the devices communicate with each other. I am not looking for any specific routing algorithms or anything like that. I would like to know how I can have the ESP8266 devices communicate with each other using the WiFi link they have established. Do I need to use the `TcpClient` and `TcpServer` classes from the Sming framework?

When a device connects with another device, I seem to be unable to retrieve the IP address of that other device.

Answer (score -1):

You could use UDP instead of TCP, it may be simpler. See the
[example Sming UDP echo code](https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/develop/samples/UdpServer_Echo/app/application.cpp).

When a UDP message is received the onReceive method receives the remote IP
address as one of its parrameters.